# How is it possible to create an array prototype function?

Tags: python

```
def array.sum():
    sm = 0
    for a in array :
        sm = sm + a
    return sm
```

Then I would like to call my function like this:

```
x = [3, 5, 6]
y = x.sum() # = 14
```

Comment: `[...]` denotes a *list* in Python.

Comment: y = sum (x) would work quite well. Why do you need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class here:

```
class my_array:
    def __init__(self, lis):
        self.array = lis
    def sum(self):
        sm = 0
        for a in self.array :
            sm += a
        return sm              #or simply use the built-in function `sum()`
...     
>>> x = my_array([3,5,6])
>>> x.sum()
14
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyList(list):
    def sum(self):
        return sum(self)
```

And then:

```
MyList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).sum()
15
```

But, I don't think you can do exactly what you want, and you should just use built-in `sum` function: `sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`

Comment: +1 for showing how to extend the original list class and for pointing out that just using the `sum` function is the actual way to go.